# Need help storing information on multiple item sand retrieve these items and display them on another screen

Tags: c#

I have a project I am currently working on and looking for some advice.

I need to be able to create multiple items which contains certain variables (mostly strings) and save these newly created items. Then I need to be able to retrieve these items data and show it on a main screen along with all the other items the user created in their own boxes.

I mostly just need help with the general concept of what I need to learn to be able to achieve this and can finish it on my own.

Concept:

The program is supposed to be where the user (a desktop user, the data is saved locally for now) can upload different plants they are currently growing and track information on it, such as the type of plant, plant lighting, and other types of variables related to growing plants.

This information is created through a popup form asking the user for the information needed. (This part is already done) This data then needs to be saved in some format (which I need help on).

This data then needs to be used to display a list on the main page of all the plants the user added, giving vital information on the plant and then having a button to allow the user to view/edit data on the plant (I have very little idea on how to do this at the moment).

Comment: You should define *items* in more depth. If these *Items* are class objects, consider JSON as format. Then, users from where? The whole globe or desktop users? If the former, each of them needs to store their own preferences/objects? Do these objects need to shared among users? (...)

Comment: @Jimi is right, we need more information.  It kind of sounds like a database application, or maybe SignalR, or... could be all sorts.  Can you describe the thing in more detail please?

Comment: @Jimi I edited the post to provide some information.

Comment: Since this data could grow in details and probably needs history and statistics reports, you probably want a solid, queryable storage. A relational Database, in practice.

Comment: [SQLite Tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/)

Comment: Step #1 needs to be to define your problem better.

Comment: An alternative idea is to store the data in an XML file. You can create your classes according to how you want the data to be stored and you can then serialize it into an XML file. Deserialize it to load the stored data into your application. This way you can design your data structure in classes (without having to worry about SQL) and you can store and retrieve using serialization.